# rotate to object Scene kit

Tags: ios, xcode, object, rotation, scenekit

So I have been working a lot in iOS8 and Scene Kit. Here is what I wont to happy the user taps on the screen and the 3D model points where the user has click.

```
    shipAngle = [self calculateAngle:location.x :location.y :shipNode.position.x   :shipNode.position.y];

    shipNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, shipAngle);
    NSLog(@"shipAngle %f",shipAngle);



- (float) calculateAngle:(CGFloat)x1 :(CGFloat)y1 :(CGFloat)x2 :(CGFloat)y2
{
// DX
float x = x2 - x1;

// DY
float y = y2 - y1;

// Perform atan2 calculation as is inexpensive in comparison to atan
// to find tangent of angle.
float baseAngle = atan2(x, y);

// Convert to radians
float radians = baseAngle  * (180.0 / M_PI);

// Adjust to give value ranging between 0 and 360.
CGFloat angle = 180 + radians;

return angle;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the model to show where on the screen the user tapped or are you trying to show where on the surface of the model the tap was?

Comment: The model is in the center. If user tap on the right corner, the model should rot the face the right corner.

Comment: are you also taking depth into consideration or is this pretty much a 2D world being rendered in 3D?

Comment: 2D being render in 3D, Just rotating on the y axes.